# Deactivating phone7 keyboard

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

Is there a way to deactivate phone7 keyboard in my project when Textbox gets focus ?

Comment: Just out of interest, why would you **not** want the keyboard enabled when a textbox has focus?

Comment: I have created my own keyboard so when Textbox gets focus phone7 keyboard comes out.so i want to disable phone7 keyboard for using my keyboard.

Comment: Why would you have your own keyboard? This would be confusing

Comment: i created a keyboard that suits well for my app with extra buttons and transparent color,looking better than phone7 keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

you can hide the keyboard by moving the focus away from the keyboard by calling

```
this.hide();
```

however this does give a flicker.. alternative is to set your textbox to be readonly. I haven't tried this approach yet

Comment: hi dave,how to call the keyboard in the GotFocus event?

Comment: which keyboard your keyboard?.. i always show it.. or you can call hide WP keyboard and in the same call, show your keyboard.

Comment: i cant get u!can u giv me a code sample for hiding phone7 keyboard. thanku

Comment: handle focus event on textbox and then use this.hide();

Comment: I have used it in past on WP7.. stopped using it after user complains of flicker but if you say you can't do it.. well there's nothing for me to say